# Spring Boot can't resolve Thymeleaf view

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I integrate Spring Boot with Thymeleaf but the web doesn't redirect or forward after the controller returns a view.
This is Thymeleaf page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>login</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}">


</head>

<body>

            <div class="cont_forms">
                <div class="cont_img_back_">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/42/U7Fc1sy5SCUDIu4tlJY3_NY_by_PhilippHenzler_philmotion.de.jpg?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=50&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=7686972873678f32efaf2cd79671673d"
                         alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="cont_form_login">
                    <a href="#" onclick="ocultar_login_sign_up()"><i class="material-icons">&#xE5C4;</i></a>
                    <h3>login</h3>
                    <input id="login_name" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
                    <input id="login_password" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                    <div class="checkbox mb-3" style="margin:5% auto 0% 2%">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="remember"> Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <p style="color: red" th:text="${msg}" th:if="${not #strings.isEmpty(msg)}"></p>
                    <button class="btn_login" onclick="login('http://localhost:8080/assignment/user/login')">login</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

<script>
    function login(url) {
        var username = document.getElementById("login_name").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("login_password").value;
        $.post(url, {'username':username, 'password':password});
    }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

And I have a controller:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TeacherRepository teacherRepository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/user/login")
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam("username") String username,
                              @RequestParam("password") String password,
                              Map<String, Object> info,
                              HttpSession session) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
            Optional<Student> student = studentRepository.findById(username);
            if (!student.isPresent()) {
                info.put("msg", "User doesn't exist.");
            } else {
                try {
                    if (!EncryptUtil.aesDecrypt(student.get().getPassword()).equals(password)) {
                        info.put("msg", "Wrong password!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("-------------------------success");
                        session.setAttribute("user", student.get().getName()); 
                        mv.setViewName("student/homework");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        return mv;
    }
}
```

I can see `------------------------success` in the console which means method `login` has exited succefully ** but the page doesn't change.** It doesn't just go to the view `student/homework`. Anyony helps?
Additionally this is the `pom.xml`:

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

-------------------------UPDATE------------------------------- 
This is the stack trace:

```
2018-08-11 12:21:29.824  INFO 13220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/assignment]    : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-08-11 12:21:29.824  INFO 13220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-08-11 12:21:29.876  INFO 13220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 52 ms
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_0_0_, student0_.name as name2_0_0_, student0_.password as password3_0_0_ from students student0_ where student0_.id=?
-------------------------success
```

Also, I find another problem. I tried to custom Spring MVC so I wrote a configuration class :

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter webMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        WebMvcConfigurerAdapter adapter = new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                // welcome page
                registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
                registry.addViewController("/index.html").setViewName("index");
            }
        };
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

But IDEA shows that `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated. What should I do? I can't find a solution in the Spring Boot reference doc.

Comment: Use `WebMvcConfigurer` instead of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter ` . one thing i suspect is the path pattern might be the cause . for secure page you should add .

Comment: @soorapadman I checked the path of view again and again but I didn't find what was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render view you need to use `@Controller`.

Change this:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {
}
```

To:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
}
```

Comment: Oh, I have tried this one but it didn't work either. It's strange.

Comment: give your stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ModelAndView, try using `Model`. Do following -

1. Use `Controller` instead of `RestController`.
2. Change return type to String.
3. Add thymeleaf attributes to your Model object.
4. Return the template name you want to display.
5. Configure the template path in your properties/YML file -

   spring.thymeleaf.prefix = classpath:/YOUR FOLDER NAME/